# ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::{closure}(), 1 passed in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo, laravel-livewire

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
> App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::{closure}(), 1 passed in
> D:\laragon\www\laraveljetstream\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\Broadcaster.php
> on line 77 and exactly 2 expected in file
> D:\laragon\www\laraveljetstream\routes\channels.php on line 21

I am always getting this error .
my channels.php

```
    Broadcast::channel('post{userId}', function ($data,$userId) {
    return response()->json(['user_id' => $userId,'data' => $post]);
});
```

Component

```
    protected $listeners = ['echo-private:post.{Auth::user()->id}' => 'notifyNewPost'];
```

I was unable to listen to this event .
Please suggest some answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `'data' => $data` instead of `'data' => $post`?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't because you need a period between `post` and `{userId}`?

```php
Broadcast::channel('post.{userId}'...
```